# Dynamically added position:fixed element is in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, css, ios10.3

In an hybrid app we have at work we disable the scrolling when a dialog opens. This is something that used to work perfect, until iOS 10.3 came around.

**The case:**

The disabling of the scroll happens when a user clicks a button. An overlay is shown with some content. To remove it they either tap the close button or the overlay. Nothing specials.

The way we disable the scrolling is by setting the following code:
(I have removed the eye candy to keep it readable. [A complete example can be found here](http://trbo.be/ios/))

*HTML:*

```
<body>
    <header onClick="unFreeze()">
        Header
    </header>

    <section></section>

    <section>
        <button onClick="freeze()">Toggle freeze</button>
    </section>

    <section></section>

    <section></section>

    <section></section>

    <section></section>

    <div class="backdrop" onClick="unFreeze()"></div>
</body>
```

*Javascript:*

```
function freeze() {
    var $body = document.querySelector('body');
    $body.style.top = (0 - window.pageYOffset) + 'px';
    $body.classList.add('body--freeze');
}

function unFreeze() {
    var $body = document.querySelector('body');
    var scrollTop = - parseInt($body.style.top);

    $body.style.top = '';
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);

    $body.classList.remove('body--freeze');
}
```

*CSS:*

```
.body--freeze {
    background-color: hotpink;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.body--freeze header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.body--freeze .backdrop {
    visibility: visible;
}

header {
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 51
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
}

.backdrop {
    bottom: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Reproduce the issue:**

Scroll down until you see the "Toggle freeze" button. Press it when it is somewhere in the middle of the screen. You will notice that the header will be positioned somewhere on the screen, but not on top. Notice that although it seems to be at the bottom, selecting of the "Header" text can still be done at it's original top position.

Click the green background or header to unfreeze the page.

This issue only happens once. The second time the header will be painted correctly.

If you scroll further until the button reaches the top of the page, the painting of the header will also be correct.

**This only occurs on iOS 10.3, all other versions work fine.**

Comment: We also see issues regarding fixed container. Absolute positioned UI elements being cut off and stuff. Remember seeing this like 4 years ago when working with iOS and fixed elements. Guess it's back.

Comment: Seeing a problem with position fixed as well...

Comment: It does seem a problem but I couldn't find any related issues at the time...

Comment: it has been fixed in the following change: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/216104/webkit

Comment: I'm facing the same issue even after the new release 10.3.2, is there any workaround?

Comment: @diegoddox we fixed it by forcing a repaint ourselves on the page. The bugfix has been merged but as far as I know not yet shipped on iOS...

Comment: Thanks @WartClaes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed by Webkit: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/216104/webkit